# How to put Mysql path in bash profile on MacBook Pro 10.6.8

Tags: bash, macintosh

I want to put a mysql path into the bash profile of my macbook pro. How do I access the bash file and then make it visible in the finder so I can open it with a text editor and put in the path?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your Finder to show all hidden files by running these commands in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

Alternately, you can just edit files using the `open` command directly:

```
open -a TextEdit .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot selectively make .bash_profile visible to the Finder.  You can either make all "invisible" files visible using `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` or not.  (I recommend not.)

You can edit .bashrc or .bash_profile from the Terminal using Emacs or VI(M).  Or you can create a file named BASHRC (or anything else) and then rename it to .bashrc or .bash_profile using the terminal.

Or you can launch TextEdit on the file using

```
open -a TextEdit .bash_profile
```